# Qt for iOS: How to open iOS component from Qt Application (i.e.from QMainWindow or QWidget or anything)?

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I have requirement to open HTML content on iOS application. Currently I am using Qt for iOS which does not have support for `QtWebKitsWidgets`. So now I am planning to open `UIWebView` using `UIViewController` of iOS from Qt application. I have tried to open `UIViewController` from dummy `UIViewController` using `presentViewController` method but it is not opening anything on `QMainWindow`.

Let me know whether such thing is possible or not. If possible then guide me through some suggestions. Let me know if more detail is required. I am modifying example given by Qt for iOS only. Note that I am using Qt5.2.0 for iOS.

Comment: See [QtWS 2015-Qt on iOS A to Z-Mike Krus video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A7DPUwIcDg) for some good information. See [this demo](https://github.com/seyedmmousavi/Native-UITextView-on-Qt-KDAB) which uses a native `UITextView` on Qt.

Answer (score 2):

The Qt documentation points to this example of how to integrate a native iOS controller with a QML application.

https://github.com/richardmg/qtdd13_qmlapp

It implements bringing up UIImagePickerController over a QML display.

So, while you can't integrate a UIWebView with QML content, you can push a new controller on containing it or maybe even can super-impose a UIWebView on top of the QML view.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible (with the Qt4iOS iOS plugin) to use `UIWebView` from `QWidget` based apps, but not QML apps. The Digia iOS plugin does not support using `UIWebView` in any way (and won’t any time soon).

Comment: May I know where to download it from? I have .dmg file installed from qtproject site for 5.2.0 and I have done complete installation. Also do you have code snippet anywhere to study?

Comment: Note that I am using xcode5. I executed qmake and converted .pro to .xcodeproj file. I did not find way to execute sample in iOS simulator using Qt Creator. So for plugin mentioned above needs to be worked with Qt creator only or I can use it with xcode?

Comment: You should work with Qt creator. It is actually a plugin which should be enabled.You can get it from here : [http://www.mediator-software.com/](http://www.mediator-software.com/)